# Detecting smile inside face using openCV in Java

Tags: java, opencv, detection

I am working on a openCV application. With some code, I am able to detect frontalfaces. I want to detect and just keep a count of the times user smiled. My idea was after the face is detected, I am drawing a rectangle around it, and at that point I would call smile detection. So far, my result are less then successful. I am posting my code for face detection, can anyone give me any pointers how to start from the for loop inside face detection. THank you.

```
 public Mat detect(Mat inputframe) {
        Mat mRgba = new Mat();
    Mat mGrey = new Mat();
    MatOfRect faces = new MatOfRect();
    inputframe.copyTo(mRgba);
    inputframe.copyTo(mGrey);
    Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, mGrey, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    Imgproc.equalizeHist(mGrey, mGrey);
    face_cascade.detectMultiScale(mGrey, faces);
    System.out.println(String.format("Detected %s face",
            faces.toArray().length));
    MatOfRect smileDetections = new MatOfRect();
    face_cascade1.detectMultiScale(mGrey,smileDetections);
    System.out.println(String.format("Detected %s smiles",smileDetections.toArray().length));
    for (Rect rect : faces.toArray()) {
        Point center = new Point(rect.x + rect.width * 0.5, rect.y
                + rect.height * 0.5);
        Core.ellipse(mRgba, center, new Size(rect.width * 0.5,
                rect.height * 0.5), 0, 0, 360, new Scalar(255, 0, 255), 4,
                8, 0);
    }
    return mRgba;
}
    }
```

Comment: what kind of cascade did you load to `face_cascade1`?

Comment: I think that the better solution is to use ASM model to recognize the facial expression, just as a smile. something like this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v8ipupeMwgo

Comment: Have you checked also the opencv sample: <OPENCVDIR>/opencv-2.4.xx/samples/c/smiledetect.cpp ?

Comment: Hello Micka, I have use smile cascade found in haarcascade folder. @Dervish : I am programming in Java, I will check it out. Code updated in edit BTW.

Answer (score 2):

Anyway, you have few choices:

1. using Active Shape Model (ASM) and Active Appearance Model (AAM), you may find easily some free open source libraries.
2. using some statistic classifiers: I think you may need to check this useful [paper](http://staff.science.uva.nl/~rvalenti/projects/mmis/Automatic%20Facial%20Emotion%20Recognition.pdf), they use Tree-Augmented-Naive Bayes (TAN) classifiers to recognize facial expressions.
3. Or you may use opencv face recognition api, but not to recognize the faces, you may define your smily faces, or even only mouthes with different cases, opencv recognizer will classify them, according to the class labels you defined. [Here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/tutorial/facerec_video_recognition.html) you find the toturial of opencv telling you how to repare your data and train them.

Comment: Thanks dervish, I am considering that as a last resort to integrate some C++ code into the Java code. That is the only option I currently have.

Comment: so, you may know applying jni for this task ?

Comment: Thanks. Thats what I plan to do.

Comment: + 1 for mentioning Bayesian.  FYI: ASM and AAM are processing intensive! As far as I know, there isn't a great haar classifier for smiles.  This is a more difficult problem than it seems.